# Insert Contacts Custom Field In Article

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, custom-field, contact

I have created a few custom fields for my **contacts**. I now want to display these contact details withinin some articles using the following format;

```
{field 1} will display the field with the ID 1
{field 1,foo} will display the selected field using the alternative layout 'foo'.
{fieldgroup 2} will display all fields within the fieldgroup with the ID 2.
```

I'm using TinyMCE editor but I can't see the 'Field' button. Example of button in this image below;

[image]

I have checked that the plugins are enabled and cleared my cache etc.

Am I not able to add contact custom fields into an article?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the fields are only available to the component for which they were created, being an extension of that component. If you think about, if you add {field 1} to an article, how does the article know that you mean field 1 from com_contacts or any other component.

Maybe one day custom fields might advance to allow {com_contacts:field 1} which would solve your issue.

You might be able to achieve what you want using an extension that allows you to embed other modules or components in your articles.

Terry